# QML import version 2.0 vs minor versions e.g. 2.12 2.15

Tags: qt, qml

I'm always confused about which import version should I use.

For example, I installed Qt version 5.12 and do `import QtQuick 2.0`. Does this mean I get the latest feature that comes with Qt 5.12? Or should I use `import QtQuick 2.12` to get the latest features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for the most up to date features, you should import the highest version of the given libraries that you have. For example, here is a stand alone test:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Binding {
        delayed: true
    }
}
```

Running this example will throw the following error and quit immediately:
`qrc:/main.qml:14 "Binding.delayed" is not available in QtQml 2.0.`

Per the version note [in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html#delayed-prop) ("This property was introduced in Qt 5.8"), changing the QtQml import to 2.8 or greater will allow this to run properly.

Comment: Thank you. I see. So 2.0 is not a shorthand for using the latest, but it references Qt 5.0.